# Why \GetTranslation from translations package cannot be used for (thmtools) theorem's name?

Tags: thmtools, translations

The following MWE works as expected:

```
\documentclass[french,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{translations}
\usepackage{babel}

\DeclareTranslationFallback{foo}{Foo}%
\DeclareTranslation{English}{foo}{Foo (English)}%
\DeclareTranslation{French}{foo}{Foo (French)}%

\def\foo{\GetTranslation{foo}}
% \declaretheorem[name=\GetTranslation{foo}]{baz}

\begin{document}
\GetTranslation{foo} = \foo

\selectlanguage{french}

\GetTranslation{foo} = \foo
\end{document}
```

except if the `\declaretheorem[name=\GetTranslation{foo}]{baz}` is commented out: in such a case, compilation fails with errors:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...@language@\@trnslt@current@language 

l.15 ...aretheorem[name=\GetTranslation{foo}]{baz}

? 
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \@trnslt@current@language 

l.15 ...aretheorem[name=\GetTranslation{foo}]{baz}

?
```

Hence my question: why `\GetTranslation` from `translations` package cannot be used for (`thmtools`) theorem's name?

Comment: Try `name=\protect{GetTranslation}{foo}`. The output is different from your MWE.. there's no `baz`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I wouldn't try protecting `{` only bad things could happen:-)

Comment: It looks like it is looking for a "current language" which i guess isn't set up until `\begin{document}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Ok, I leave it to you ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer With `name=\protect\GetTranslation{foo}`, it works like a charm. Could you create an answer in order I can accept it?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé: No, I think the idea by David Carlisle is better!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But it works with `\def\foo{\GetTranslation{foo}}` (and, finally, with `\declaretheorem[name=\protect\GetTranslation{foo}]{baz}`).

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I explained why it failed, but not how to stop it failing, \protect/noexpand will delay the language lookup until the theorem is used, which is just what you want here

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I'm not against that, but which David's idea? ;)

Comment: @DenisBitouzé with `\def` the replacement text is never evaluated at until `\foo` is used, but `\declaretheorem` is doing more work and is clearly expanding some of its arguments at the point of definition, hence `\protect` to stop that.

Comment: `translations` defines `\def\@trnslt@current@language{\languagename}` only at the end of the preamble. Probably `\declaretheorem` expands its `name` (which would defeat using `\GetTranslation{...}` as name in the first place…)

Comment: Indeed `\thmt@thmname` (set by `name=...`) is found inside `\protected@edef` so often I lost track…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've to protect `\GetTranslation` from being executed at the point of definition in `\declaretheorem` -- the call to `\GetTranslation` is deferred to the point where the theorem itself is used, i.e. in 
the document body:

```
 \declaretheorem[name=\protect\GetTranslation{foo}]{baz}
```

Thanks to David Carlisle also for some explanations ;-)